# Function returns an error #Value! when I try to use it

Tags: excel, vba

What is the reason an error appears when I want to return the value of my function?

```
Public Function Alphabet_SEF() As Integer
Dim AllAreAlphabetic As Boolean
Dim ReturnVal As Integer
    AllAreAlphabetic = True
    Sheets("BlaBla").Activate
    For i = 1 To Sheets("BlaBla").Range("E1", Range("E1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
       If (VarType(Range("E1")) <> 8) Then
          AllAreAlphabetic = False
          Exit For
       End If
    Next
    Sheets("CdM").Activate
    If (AllAreAlphabetic) Then
        ReturnVal = 1
    Else
        ReturnVal = 0
    End If
    Alphabet_SEF = ReturnVal
End Function
```

When I put in my Excel book "=Alphabet_SEF()" appear `#value`!

Comment: `Sheets("BlaBla").Range("E1", Range("E1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count` will error if "BlaBla" is not the active sheet, because that `Range("E1")` will by default refer to the active sheet...  `Sheets("BlaBla").Activate` will not resolve that in a UDF, because UDF are restricted from actions like that.  If you want to debug your function, then call it from a Sub or from the Immediate pane in the VB editor.

Comment: One unrelated note is to never use `Integer` in VBA, but instead use `Long`.  This is because `Integer` is 16-bit and can overflow easily (for values of 32767). `Long` is the equivalent of `int` or `Integer` on _all_ other languages.

Comment: Finally, a user-defined function (UDF) in Excel has some limitations which prevent them from making modification to worksheets, including `.Activate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - it does not rely on BlaBla being active

```
Public Function Alphabet_SEF() As Boolean
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range

    Application.Volatile 'forces recalculation: use when you have no parameters for
                         '  Excel to use to determine when it needs to be recalculated
    With Sheets("BlaBla")
        Set rng = .Range(.Range("E1"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp))
    End With
    
    For Each c In rng.Cells
       If VarType(c) <> 8 Then
          Alphabet_SEF = False 'set to false and exit function
          Exit Function
       End If
    Next
    
    Alphabet_SEF = True 'if got here then all values are type 8
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks man, your code helped me a lot and I learned something new. I don't know how delete the before post